# Как настроить postgresql pitr в docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker, резервное-копирование

Есть БД postgresql в докере. Стоит задача настроить инкрементальный бекап.
В создании контейнера прописаны скрипты на создание пользователей, БД и прав, проброс файлов с контейнера в систему.
Что я делаю дальше:

1. `"apk add rsync"` и `"apk add openssh"`. Потом через "`su - postgres`" я настраиваю ssh ключик и пробрасываю его к себе локально, чтобы в будующем можно было задать команды для сохранения wal файлов к себе локально (в будующем на другой сервер для безопасноти хранения этих файлов).
2. Потом создаю в докере папочки для бекапа,
   форматирую конфиг, а именно: replica/archive, off на on и прописываю команды для записи и восстановления файлов wal. Я это делаю через sed.
3. Создаю точку сохранения или как это верно назвать:

   su - postgres
   psql -c "SELECT pg_start_backup('label');" postgres
   tar -C /var/lib/postgresql/data/ -czvf /stor/backups/pg_basebackup_backup.tar.gz .
   psql -c "SELECT pg_stop_backup();" postgres
4. Потом я накачиваю БД и wal файлы пишутся мне локально, с этим всё ОК.
5. Дальше нужно протестировать как сработает восстановление, нужно ломать и строить. И тут проблемы.

Вообще у меня получалось восстановить после удаления файлов, но это было не всегда и без понимания как это точно работает.
В инструкции нужно остановить БД, удалить файлы, разархивировать точку которую мы создавали, прописать команду для восстановления файлов wal (я это сразу делаю) и запустить БД.

Но в докере нету возможности остановить postgresql как я понял. Я прямо в докере кошу папку data, потом распаковываю туда точку начала бекапа и перезапускаю докер. И вот тут я не понимаю что происходит. Иногда контейнер падает и больше его не поднять. Иногда всё восстанавливается.

Мне нужно понять железно как это работает и как этим пользоваться. Я думал, что если у меня есть точка монтирования и набор wal файлов, то я могу создать новый контейнер, заменить data и запустить восстановление по файлам. Но так не получается.
Мне кажется что так и должно работать, но конкретно такую задачу у меня нагуглить не получилось. Не бейте(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал докер на убунте, потом установил туда постгрес. Проблема в том была, что нужно 100% останавливать постгрес при восстановлении. В докере на альпине нельзя было так сделать, при остановке процесса постгреса он падал. А теперь всё отлично работает.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).